# filling a php array from a text file

Tags: php, arrays

I am designing a file serving system, I want to be able to add links, files and other things to it from a html form, I can save the text entered into a text file, but that is no use to the array, how do I save the contents of the text file to the array? like array = file_get_contents('array-file-list.txt');

Comment: You need to load the contents of the file (or wherever the information comes from), parse it and store the tokens your parser extracts for you into your array. So you need to build a parser, unless you are using a format an existing parser can process. The latter is the typical approach, actually.

Comment: You will need to add much more detailed information to your question above to get more specific hints or even a usable answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need any special processing, [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) should do what you're looking for

```
$lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```